# Generating pdf using generic handler (ashx)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I got a requirement to create pdf on the fly from the data stored in database.
I am using html, jquery and WCF in my application.

I don't find a way to generate pdf (Show in a browser or as an attachment) using client technology (jquery, or any other client plugins). I tried to use pdf.js, but could not able to succeed. Later I used .net generic handler to generate pdf. I was passing bytearray to handler, in turn pdf started rendering on client.

I got some random issue, then I wrote a sample application to make sure handler is working fine. I used same code with a static text to generate pdf, but it started throwing a error on the client.

Below is the code snippet I used

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=download");
context.Response.Write("Hello World");
//context.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello world"));
//context.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world"));
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

I am getting errors on all the browsers
Failed to load pdf document on Chrome.
An error occurred while loading the PDF. PDF.js v0.8.505 (build: da1c944) Message: InvalidPDFException - In mozilla firefox
File does not begin with '%PDF-' in IE.

Note: I tried with aspx page too. I cant create physical file due security issues. If there is any better way of achieving it please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for your time.

Handler content type doesn't format data in the format mentioned.
It expects data in the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF is a standard file format.You cannot write a normal text file and rename it to filename.pdf and wish it to work.
You will need [.Net libraries](http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx)  for that.There are lot try googling `.Net pdf library`

Some Info.

- pdf.js is just for viewing in browser.
- setting `context.Response.ContentType` just tells the browser the file its gonna receive,So it can use existing mapped application to open it.Like Adobe browser plugin for pdf file.